# Oracle выборка дат

Tags: oracle

Есть поле `DATE_CR` в формате `Date` со значением типа `30.09.15`.
Могу сделать выборку по конкретной дате

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table  where  to_date(DATE_CR,'dd.mm.yy') = to_date('30.09.15','dd.mm.yy');
```

Как сделать выборку только по годам, по месяцам и по дням?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

попробуй это

```sql
SELECT * FROM CLS_USER_LOG   
where  to_date(DATE_CR,'dd.mm.yy') >= 
to_date('01.01.15','dd.mm.yy') and 
to_date(DATE_CR,'dd.mm.yy') <= 
to_date('31.12.15','dd.mm.yy');
```

Comment: Ооо. Спасибо. Работает.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы из даты получить конкретное значение года, месяца, дня и т.п. можно использовать функцию [extract](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm), например:

```
select extract(year from sysdate) from dual --вернет 2015
select extract(month from sysdate) from dual --вернет 9
select extract(day from sysdate) from dual --вернет 30
```

Тогда запрос будет иметь вид:

```
select * 
from Table  
where extract(year from DATE_CR) = 2015
```

**Так же** можно использовать функцию [trunc](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php), например:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'yy') from dual --вернет 01.01.2015
select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') from dual --вернет 01.09.2015
```

Тогда запрос будет иметь вид:

```
select * 
from Table  
where trunc(DATE_CR, 'yy') = date'2015-01-01'
```

Comment: а как в Java написать запрос  SELECT u FROM UserLog  u where u.id is not null  and extract(year from  u.dateCr)= ?2    не получается.

Comment: Что именно не получается? Какая-то ошибка появляется?

Answer (score 1):

Если реально дата в формате Date, то можно совсем просто:

```
SELECT * FROM Table  where  extract(year from DATE_CR) = 2015;
```

Соответственно для месяца:

```
SELECT * FROM Table  where  extract(year from DATE_CR) = 2015 and extract(month from DATE_CR) = 10;
```

Ну или как было указано выше, делать trunc до необходимого показателя:

```
--год
SELECT * FROM Table  where  trunc(DATE_CR,'year') = to_date('01.01.2015','dd.mm.yyyy');
--месяц
SELECT * FROM Table  where  trunc(DATE_CR,'month') = to_date('01.10.2015','dd.mm.yyyy');
--день
SELECT * FROM Table  where  trunc(DATE_CR) = to_date('30.10.2015','dd.mm.yyyy');
```